# find optimal values in a system of equations

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

Hi i need to solve an equation in order to find the optimal temperature, based on a 
regression model:

i have the following temperatures:

```
X1 = [80;60;40]
X2 = [60;40;20]

 y = -233.9685 + 3.7821X1 + 6.4403X2
```

optimal temperature y is around 385C

i would like to find both the optimal setting for the specific X1 and X2 values, their minimal values.
And also the optimal settings for the values with in the range of X1 and X2.

I am not very skilled in matlab, any help with the code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the first part of the question: The simplest solution is to iterate over X1 and X2 and search for the minimum.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Daniel, but i am not sure how to do that, my experience with matlab is limited to a crash course.

Comment: i thought this was easy to do in matlab, if i just need to find the minimal values for both x1 and x2, how would i write that?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What is "optimal setting"?